# Oracle Date Time strig format

Tags: string, oracle, date, time, average

I have the following oracle table, where datetime is in a single column & has datatype as string

```
f_ID      f_type    f_date

1001      A         3/30/14 12:20:00 PM

1001      B         3/30/14 10:20:00 AM

1002      A         2/3/14 11:0:00 AM

1002      B         2/3/14 9:00:00 AM

1003      A         2/13/14 10:00:00 AM

1003      B         12/13/14 10:00:00 AM

1111      B         12/13/14 10:00:00 AM
```

I wish to calculate average time taken for all shipments which have count > 1. So time difference in shipment of 1001 is 2 hours, 1002 is 2 hours, 1003 is 10 Months (303 x 24=7272) hours. 1111 has count =1 so it can be excluded from average.

So the average result should be `(2+2+7272)/3 = 2425.33 hours`.

How do I query that?

Comment: For each f_id, is there always 1 record with f_type = 'B' and 0 or 1 record with f_type = 'A'?  Also, I think your sample calculation is wrong - the time diff for 1001 looks like 2 hours, and for 1003 it is 10 months.

Comment: Yes Peter, Thank for th correction. i have edited it

Comment: for each f_id record, f_type can be A, B or C making f_id and f_type form composite key.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT f_ID, ABS(b.f_date-a.f_date)*24 AS duration
    FROM my_table a
        JOIN my_table b USING (f_ID)
    WHERE a.f_type = 'A'    
        AND a.f_type = 'B')
SELECT AVG(duration)
FROM t;
```

Comment: "ORA-01722: invalid number"  at f_date.  Please note that f_date is string type.

Comment: That's very stupid! Make a cast like `TO_DATE(b.f_date, 'FmMM/FmDD/RR FmHH:FmMI:ss AM')-TO_DATE(a.f_date, 'FmMM/FmDD/RR FmHH:FmMI:ss AM')`